# Are variables in discord.py local to each discord server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was wondering if each variable I make for a discord.py bot is local to each server. For example, if I create a variable called Highscore, and one server gets a high score of 29, setting the variable to 29, would the variable be 29 only for the one server which set the variable, or for every server the bot is in?
If this needs clarification please let me know...

Comment: Variables follow normal python scoping rules. If its declared in a function, its local to the function. If its declared in a module, its local to the module. It is not relevant to discord server at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discord.py is not an exception. All rules apply the same way as any different python program. So when you declare a variable "Highscore" it's not set only for one server. If you want to have different values for each server I would suggest using [dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) which you can later use in the database (ex. MongoDB).

Example dictionary **"Highscore"**:

```
highscore = {"server1_id": 29, "server2_id": 50}
```

Comment: So I would have to create a dictionary for every server my bot is in?

Comment: No, the dictionary contains the information for the two servers with the id `server1_id` and `server2_id`. You could theoretically save a dictionary in them that holds all the variables for the server.

Comment: @EpicEfeathers if I answered your question I would really appreciate you accepting my answer. If I didn't let me know I'll try to help :D

Comment: Yes this helped sorry about that! By the way, do you know how I could have the bot automatically create a dictionary every time it is added to a server so I could have a dictionary entry for each server the bot is in?

Comment: No problem! It just motivates me and others to answer. I would suggest making one dictionary ex. `guilds = {}` and then use [on_guilds_join()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?%20join#discord.on_guild_join) to add guild.id to your dictionary. Also, check [MongoDB](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_getstarted.asp) it's much better than keeping info in variables.